# Keyboard shortcut to open folder with Sublime Text

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, sublimetext

Is there a way to define a keyboard shortcut that would open a whole folder with Sublime Text?

I can (obviously) easily open a file, I managed to define such a shortcut for opening a Terminal window at the folder location through keyboard preferences, but I don't know how to do that for 3rd party apps.

Comment: you can also just drag a folder from finder onto the subl icon in your dock which i find quite useful.

Comment: Thank you ! I'd prefer using the keyboard than dragging the folder but this is good to know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open *System Preferences*

Select *Keyboard*, then the *Shortcuts* tab

In the left pane, click on *Services*

In the right pane, scroll to *Files and Folders*

Select *Open in Sublime Text* (or *Add to Sublime Text*) and click *add shortcut*

Select a shortcut.

Comment: This is exactly what I tried but I don't have any option related to Sublime Text in _Files and Folders_

Comment: Using [this tutorial](https://gist.github.com/idleberg/fc0df222e1df258d525d704042d72582) I created an automator _service_, and now the service appears in _Files and Folders_, so I was able to create the shortcut.